# How to use Helidon for a command-line app?

Tags: helidon

I am writing a Java command-line application intended to read and write from a database and just finish executing, once it is done with its work.

It will never expose a REST interface to anyone nor will it need to start a server and listen on any ports.

So the app is something like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
       // Start Helidon CDI, JTA, etc. - but not JAX-RS
       // No: Server.create().start();
       // No: io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.Main.main(args);

       // Do work
       MyApp myApp = CDI.current().select(MyApp.class).get();
       app.run();

       // Shutdown
       io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.Main.shutdown();
    }
}
```

But however I initialize the Helidon framework a web server is launched and starts to listen on port 8080 (or whatever). Even when using Helidon's Main.main(...) method a web server is launched.

So how do I startup/initialize Helidon for use with a command-line app with CDI, JTA, JPA but no web server?

In terms of Spring Boot I think I am requesting the Helidon equivalent of a `CommandLineRunner`.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is start a CDI container so that your application can be managed by CDI, then you could probably just use [`SeContainerInitializer`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/3.0/apidocs/index.html?jakarta/enterprise/inject/se/SeContainerInitializer.html), which is just ordinary CDI.  You can do this with or without Helidon.

If you want to use the Helidon JPA/JTA features, they are exposed via ordinary CDI portable extension machinery, so just put them on your classpath.

Comment: Hmm... if I try this a web server is still started on http://localhost:8080 and I get a warning that GraalVM native images are not supported. I will take a deeper look.

Comment: If the component containing Helidon's webserver is on the classpath it will start a webserver; maybe that's your issue.

Comment: It is certainly better supported and documented in Quarkus: https://quarkus.io/guides/command-mode-reference